# OpenCV VideoCapture can't run with 3 cameras

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I am running this class function in loop and plotting the return image at the same time. However, if I have more than 2 cameras this does not seem to work.
I have this error (continuously):

```
CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147483638
```

```
def grab_frame(self):
    image = []
    timestamp = []
    for i in range(0, len(self.devs)):
        cap = self.cams[i]
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            timestamp.extend([time.time()-self.def_time])
            image.extend(frame)
    return timestamp, image
```

Comment: cap.read is blocking until a new image is available. You will probably have to capture each cam in another thread and choose image pairs according to their timestamps afterwards.

Comment: @Micka and why does it block when there are 3 cameras but not when there are 2?

Comment: it is always blocking until there is a new image. Maybe it is a bandwidth problem or a timeout. The more cameras you try to capture in your serial capturing, the more dead time there will be for each camera. Whether this is a problem or not depends on the driver. Does each pair of 2 cameras work in your 2-camera version?

Comment: you could learn to run for-loop without `range(len())` - `for cap in self.cams:`